# How can I reload my js files when I restart my tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, browser

When I update and reset my `web project`, client browser were unable get the newest `js` files.

So how to solve this problem.

I will appreciate that you can give me some advice

Comment: cache maybe the problem.in tomcat go to temp folder tomcat-7.0.42\temp\xxx you can delete or modify temp. If browser cache Control +Shift+Delete to clear cache. Question not clear whether old JS are still loading or not.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your js file had updated in tomcat.
if the file is newest in tomcat.
The reason is the broswer cache.try to clear the brower cache.

If you use chrome,you can try this:
[image]

I usually use a chrome plugin to clear cache,The plugin  named `Clear Cache`,you can find this plugin in chrome webstore.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

or load js file like below

```
<script>
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/test.js?"+Math.random();+"'></script>");
</script>
```